# What other solutions do you use besides A/B tests for testing the efficiency of two site structures?

Tags: usability-testing, ab-testing

I've designed new site structures for one of our clients, and want to test which brings better conversion rates.

- using A/B testing seems obvious but are there any other solutions to cite differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conversion rates are something you can only test with users.  However, functionality and other usability issues can be analyzed without users.  For example:

- Number of clicks necessary to complete a function--the lower the better
- Using the same set of tasks and running through the interface
- How noticeable are the important buttons?

If, all other things being equal, one design forces more steps on the user, the barrier of entry is too high and you will have lower conversion rates.  Also, if the important buttons are prominent on one design, but not on another you will have lower conversion rates.  Big red glowing buttons are hard to resist--but might overpower your design.  You'll be able to at least predict what you are going to see before you do the testing.

If, all things being equal (how noticeable the buttons are, and the number of steps needed), you'll find that it really depends on your audience.  People are notoriously hard to predict some times.

Comment: I would really like to test that the new or the old design converts better! 
The website is on and running, and our client has to see that the new 'structure' has better results. Thus conversion is almost the only measure.
I've asked this question, to find out are there any other soltuions like A/B testing with which I could measure the conversion rate-s of different versions.

Comment: Did you analyze what would prevent people from converting and address those problems?  If so, try out a beta for a while and see if things improve.  If not, go back to the drawing board until you find what the issues really are.

Comment: Yes we have analyzed the problem, and now would like to test the solution! Now I'm just looking for any other method similar to A/B testing through which 2 different designs can be evaluated.

Comment: I don't think there is another or better method for testing your results.

Answer (score 0):

There are endless tools you can use to increase conversions, it's a whole world that like many other things (SEO for example), that has a lot to do with UX design, but often requires a separate set of skills that might have more to do with marketing.

To name a few tools that you should check out:

- Multi-variant testing (The most famous tool is probably Google Optimizer)
- pricing
- Testimonials
- Reassurance logos

Check out this blog post for more ideas: http://www.conversion-rate-experts.com/articles/101-google-website-optimizer-tips/